# What's the issue with my HTML DropDownList not displaying the created SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been messing around with some ASP.NET MVC code and I'm trying to create a DropDownList via the HTML Helper in a view, but I try and create the SelectList separately and then pass the object reference into the DropDownList, it doesn't show up when I run the code. It shows up as a blank area next to the label. By the way, I'm well aware of the DropDownListFor method, I'm just curious as to why this doesn't work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
    <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
    <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
    <p>Test: @Html.TextBox("Test")</p>
    <p>Test2: 
        @{ List<SelectListItem> a = new List<SelectListItem>();
            a.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Jake", Value = "Jake" });
            a.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Sam", Value = "Sam" });
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> b = new SelectList(a);
            Html.DropDownList("Test2", b, "Choose a name");
         }
   </p>
```

This is what it looks like

[RSVPForm in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1WkI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the SelectList completely, and the call to `DropDownList` needs to be preceded with '@'

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
    <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
    <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
    @*<p>Phone: @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.WillAttend)</p>*@
    <p>Test: @Html.TextBox("Test")</p>
    <p>Test2: 
        @{ List<SelectListItem> a = new List<SelectListItem>();
            a.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Jake", Value = "Jake" });
            a.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Sam", Value = "Sam" });

            //string c = (string)b.SelectedValue;
         }
        @Html.DropDownList("Test2", a, "Choose a name");
   </p>
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it needs to be prefaced with an @? I thought even though it was in a razor block, it would apply that to the call to DropDownList.... I guess I can't really apply C# code block concepts to razor...

Comment: The call to `DropDownList` returns a variable of type `IHtmlString`.  As your code was previously, you were calling the function but not using the returned value. '@' means you want to inject it into the page.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.